# Spring Boot Security: How to skip login for localhost?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

My working spring boot SecurityConfig currently looks like this:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/error", "/webjars/**", "/login", "**/favicon.ico").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?state=badauth")
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/processLogin")
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            .failureHandler(failureHandler())
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login?state=loggedout");
    ;
    }
```

I am trying to allow users on the localhost to gain access to all resources without logging in. I have tried to insert the following into various locations within the chain:

```
.antMatchers("/**").access("hasIpAddress(\"127.0.0.1\") or hasIpAddress(\"::1\")")
```

Which always causes non-localhost access to fail with a forbidden.

How can I bypass login for users on the localhost only?

Comment: It's not what you are asking but you could use profile to parameterize `HttpSecurity` differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/secured")
    public ResponseEntity secured() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Access granted");
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('::1') or isAuthenticated()")  // 127.0.0.1 and localhost do not need to authenticate on any url
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: that did it. It appears the " or isAuthenticated()" was the missing link. Thank you!

Comment: @Oliver with authorizeHttpRequests how does it work? .access doesn't accept strings

Answer (score -1):

Try to add hasIpAddress() before authenticated like this:

```
.antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1").anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: That didn't work for non-localhost users: After login form the '/' request matches on the /** universal pattern and then throws an "Access is denied (user is not anonymous)"

Answer (score -1):

You can try disabling default security in Spring Boot by adding this line in `application.properties` file of your local/dev profile:

 `security.basic.enabled=false`

Comment: Or you can use Java-based configuration if you're only looking to disable Spring boot security : 
 `@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
     security.httpBasic().disable();
    }
}`

Comment: Do let me know if these solutions worked out for you.