# Allow only from localhost with Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I've found a [cookbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958780/spring-boot-security-how-to-skip-login-for-localhost) for allowing requests in Spring Boot 2:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('::1') or isAuthenticated()")  // 127.0.0.1 and localhost do not need to authenticate on any url
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
}
```

However, I'm unable to find how to make it with Spring Boot 3, where there no `access` method that takes String, neither have I found corresponding `AuthorizationManager` implementation that could do what I need.

How do I allow localhost only in Spring Boot 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html)

You should do something like this:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       ...
        IpAddressMatcher hasIpAddress = new IpAddressMatcher("127.0.0.1");
        
        request.authorizeHttpRequests(requestMatcherRegistry -> {
          requestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/path/**").access(((authentication, object) ->
              new AuthorizationDecision(hasIpAddress.matches(object.getRequest()))
          ));
          requestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest().denyAll();
        });
    ...
    return request.build();
```