# How to skip Spring security authentication for certain users?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to build an app that has two types of users. One is that needs to go through normal authentication via Spring Security and the other set of users can directly access the app without going through any kind of authentication. (We will differentiate users based on their IP Addresses.) Also I am using Spring Security 6.

How to achieve this. Any help and guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote an answer about how to allow request from specific [ipAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77087745/allow-only-from-localhost-with-spring-boot-3/77087933#77087933) you can start from there an customise it how you want

Comment: Hello @AndreiLisa Thanks for your answer. It is very helpful. I need one more help. How to do a log.info of such users who went through ip address matching and so skipped the Spring Security authentication.

Comment: how the users will have access to back-end ? by jwt token(bearer) or basic as username/password ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa oauth2.  if the user ip did not match then via oauth2 they will have access and if ip matched then they do not need to do any login

Comment: In case of oAuth 2.0 it is not possible because all authentication/authorization is on authorization server side not resource server side. By the way, one more question just to have more details, are you writing your own authorization server, I mean application like Keycloak based on spring-boot-authorization-server starter ?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom authentication mechanism based on IP addresses. You can create a custom filter that checks the incoming request's IP address and, if it matches a predefined set of IP addresses for unauthenticated users, allows access without further authentication.
To implement this, create a custom filter by extending Spring Security's OncePerRequestFilter. In the filter, retrieve the request's IP address and compare it with the list of allowed IP addresses. If a match is found, grant access without authentication. Otherwise, proceed with normal authentication.
Example of a custom IP-based filter:

```
public class IpAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final List<String> allowedIpAddresses = Arrays.asList("192.168.1.100", "192.168.1.101");

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String clientIpAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

        if (allowedIpAddresses.contains(clientIpAddress)) {
            // Grant access without further authentication
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // Continue with normal authentication
            super.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
        }
    }
}
```

Configure the Custom Filter:

Configure the custom IP-based authentication filter in your Spring Security configuration. You can specify the order of the filter to ensure it is executed before the standard authentication filters.
Example of configuring the custom filter:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.addFilterBefore(new IpAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // Other Spring Security configurations...
    }
}
```